# Issue in update with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Since I am new to angularjs, I am sorry beforehand if you find this question inappropriate. 
I am trying to update a record by sending put request:

```
 $scope.save = function (editedEmp) {
                    alert(editedEmp.Id);
                    alert(editedEmp.FirstName);
                    alert(editedEmp.LastName);
                    alert(editedEmp.Email);
                    $http.put('/api/Employee', editedEmp)
                        .success
                            (
                                function (data) {
                                    alert('saved successfully');
                                    editedEmp.editmode = false;
                                }
                            )
                        .error
                            (
                                function (ts) {
                                    alert('An error occurred');
                                    alert(ts.responseStatus);
                                    $scope.error = "Error occurred during update";
                                }
                            )
                };
```

I am calling this save method like:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="save(emp)" ng-show="emp.editmode" ng-click = "toggleEdit(emp)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

I get all the values correct in alert but still it throws some exception, I tried to view the exception by responseStatus/responseText but it comes blank.

Could please someone guide me what am I doing wrong here ?

I am referring to following article:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/crud-operations-in-mvc-5-using-webapi-with-angularjs/

Comment: What do you mean by "it throws some exception"? What is the exception stack trace? Also, you have 2 ng-click attributes on the button. This is invalid. Finally, the first argument of the error() callback is the data, not the full response. Its arguments are `data, status, headers, config`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!!! Issue was in format of request being sent. I changed the PUT request call to $http.put('/api/Employee/' + editedEmp.Id, editedEmp)....and all went well

Answer (score 0):

```
    Service.Js Code
   // Update Poll Question 
      this.updatePollQuestion = function (pollquestion) {
        var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Poll/UpdatePollQuestion",
        data: JSON.stringify(pollquestion),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
  Controller.js Code
  app.controller("pollCntrl", function ($scope, angularService) {
  $scope.editPollQuestion = function (pollquestion) {
    var getData = angularService.getQuestion(pollquestion.QId);
    getData.then(function (pques) {
        $scope.pollquestion = pques.data;
        $scope.QId = pollquestion.QId;
        $scope.QText = pollquestion.QText;
        $scope.Other = pollquestion.Other;
        $scope.Status = pollquestion.Status;
        $scope.Action = "Update";
        $scope.divPollQuestion = true;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error in getting records');
    });
}
```

}

```
    PollController.cs Code

    public string UpdatePollQuestion(PollQuestion pques)
    {
        if (pques != null)
        {
            using (DemoContext contextObj = new DemoContext())
            {
                int pquesId = Convert.ToInt32(pques.QId);
                PollQuestion pollQuestion = contextObj.pollquestion.Where(a           => a.QId == pquesId).FirstOrDefault();
                pollQuestion.QText = pques.QText;
                pollQuestion.Other = pques.Other;
                pollQuestion.Status = pques.Status;
                contextObj.SaveChanges();
                return "Poll Question Updated Susccesfully";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Record";
        }
    }
```